# ListView with checkboxes android studio

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm having trouble getting my checkboxes checked when any of the functions(which are commented out now) are called inside my listView onItemClickedListener. toggleChecked should only update my database and RefreshList is supposed to update my listView.
My onItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ListItemDetails listItemDetails = (ListItemDetails) arrayAdapter.getItem(i);

                //toggleChecked(i, view);

                //RefreshList(arrayAdapter);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.listitems_checkbox);
                checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
            }
        });
```

toggleChecked function

```
public void toggleChecked(final Integer i,final View view)
    {
        final DatabaseReference RootRef;
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        RootRef.child("Lists").child(ListDetails.getID()).child("listitems").child(arrayList.get(i).getID()).child("checked").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String checked = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("checked",(checked.equals("0") ? "1" : "0"));

                RootRef.child("Lists").child(ListDetails.getID()).child("listitems").child(arrayList.get(i).getID()).updateChildren(map);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

RefreshList function

```
public void RefreshList(final ArrayAdapter<ListItemDetails> arrayAdapter) {
        DatabaseReference reference;
        reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Lists");
        reference.child(ListDetails.getID()).child("listitems").orderByChild("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                arrayList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    ListItemDetails temp = new ListItemDetails();
                    String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    temp.setName(name);
                    String ID = ds.child("ID").getValue(String.class);
                    temp.setID(ID);
                    String checked = ds.child("checked").getValue(String.class);
                    temp.setChecked(checked);
                    arrayList.add(temp);
                }
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                for(int i=0; i<listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                {
                    View v = getViewByPosition(i,listView);
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.listitems_checkbox);
                    if(arrayList.get(i).getChecked().equals("1"))
                    {
                        checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

XML for the adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:id="@+id/textt">
    </TextView>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/listitems_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter is declared like this

```
final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ListItemDetails>(this, R.layout.list_items_checkbox, R.id.textt, arrayList);
```

Comment: A CheckBox wil check/uncheck when a user clicks it. Why are you setting the checked value when onItemClicked is triggered? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I check it on the onItemClicked becouse the checkbox is not clickable, but it does not work if i check it on the onItemClicked

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way around this, I call the toggleChecked() inside a setOnCheckedListener for the checkbox, checkboxes work this way, but my setOnCheckedListener does not work properly, it only ever reaches toggleChecked() whenever I uncheck a certain checkbox.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ListItemDetails listItemDetails = (ListItemDetails) arrayAdapter.getItem(i);
            final Integer newi = i;

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_checkbox);
            checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());

            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    toggleChecked(newi);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are only setting an oncheckedchangelistener when the user clicks an item. And only on the checkbox of that item. You should of course give all checkboxes in all items such a listener. And without the user having to click an item first. To do so you should extend the arrayadapter class and give every checkbox such a listener in getView().

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I figured I can just display a text from the database to indicate that the listitem is "done", anyways thank you for your time! Have a great day